# I have a question about the DDPM equation derivation related to the multiplication and division of Gaussian distributions

Tags: deep-learning, gaussian

[image]

The equation involves multiplying two Gaussian distributions and dividing by another Gaussian distribution, which cannot be solved using the method of multiplying and dividing probability density functions as far as I know. How can we obtain this equation?"

Answer (score 0):

From Appendix A of Variational Diffusion Model
[image]

Note that it is a continuous case, but we can change it into discrete case by letting s=i-1, t=i,z=x, x=x0(our data).

To derive from your formula (two gaussian divided by another gaussian), the denominator can be ignored, since it is a normalization constant (cuz x[i] and x0 are given) to make the total possibility to be 1, thus the sampling process is only dependent on the numerator. (Same as ignoring the third term in eq.73)

To compute the product of two gaussian distributions, you have to arrange the exponential term in a form of exp( -( (x[i-1] - mean)^2 + Constant) / (2 * variance)) ). You can ignore all constant terms just like the denominator.

Derivation below is from https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.11970

[image]